# Can't run WSL from the CLI (cmd or powershell) Unless as Administrator

Tags: powershell, wsl2

I have a strange situation. I cannot invoke wsl from the command line or powershell unless I do so with elevated (admin) privileges. I think I was able to do so until I upgraded to WSL2 (to allow running Docker, for instance.)

Is that how it is supposed to be?

Or is it because I accidentally installed/upgraded it as an Administrator?

Is there a way to get this to work as a non-admin (without having to reinstall the whole thing)?

Thanks.

PS. C:\Windows\system32 is in the system's path as well as in the non-elevated path.

However, wsl.exe under the system32 directory is not "visible" when doing a `dir` command from the command line as a non-elevated user.

It is only visible from the command line when it is run as an Administrator.

What is stranger, is that, I can run wsl.exe by double-clicking it from the File Explorer (without a need to have elevated privileges.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Nope. That's one of the last links I checked before asking the question. My non-elevated path is fine as far as I can tell.

Comment: This administrator was the built-in one or an account you created? This machine connected to a AD domain?

Comment: I guess I misspoke. I didn't use an administrator account. I was logged in as myself, and I installed WLS2 using elevated privileges. This is a corp laptop where I'm supposed to be a power user (can install most things provided I elevate privileges.)

Answer (score 2):

Do you run an alternative terminal application for your main user, but perhaps use the "normal" Windows Console when launching an elevated/administrator terminal?

Since you:

- *Can* see and launch `wsl.exe` from File Explorer in `C:\Windows\System32`, but ...
- *Cannot* see `wsl.exe` when issuing a `dir` command from the PowerShell or CMD in `C:\Windows\System32`

The most likely cause (but perhaps not the only one) is that you are running in a 32-bit terminal.

Try `dir C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe` in your existing terminal/shell.  If you find `wsl.exe` using that method, then you are running 32-bit.

If that's the case, I'd recommend switching to Windows Terminal (installable from the Microsoft Store).  It is:

- A modern replacement for the legacy Windows Console
- Actively developed by Microsoft
- Feature rich (arguably the most of any terminal apps for Windows, and possibly for Linux, even)
- Open-source ([Github repo](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal))
- Can automatically detect any WSL, PowerShell, CMD, Git Bash, etc. installations and automatically create a profile for them.
- And perhaps most importantly in this case, 64-bit :-)

Comment: C:\Windows\Sysnativ doesn't exist. I am executing directly on a Dell development laptop running Windows 10 Enterprise (64bit), up to date with all service packs as far as I can tell.  I am baffled by this issue.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @luis.espinal What's your terminal?  Just Windows Console?